# Why is non-linearity the key for mixers?

Tags: circuit-design

I am confused about circuits that multiply two signals.  Before reading about how mixers work, I imagined that to multiply two signals it would be enough to bias a MOSFET transistor into its linear region, apply one signal to its base and another to its drain.  Then I realized that for sinusoidal signals this would not work because the MOSFET would cutoff whenever the voltage of the first signal would drop below the threshold voltage. Now, after reading about how mixers work, I'm trying to understand why non-linearity of a diode or a MOSFTET is the key to their function.

Comment: for example, (a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab <- there's your ab, if you can separate it from the rest...

Comment: A linear system, in the electronic sense, can only add, amplify, delay, or attenuate. In particular, it can't multiply.

Comment: Multiplication by an independent signal (like an LO) is linear, but time-varying if that independent signal changes with time.  That doesn't mean a practical analog multiplier can be built with all linear components, though.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, driving the gate of a FET with one RF signal while driving it's source with another is a practical (if simple and low performance) way of implementing a mixer.  Same thing with a BJT, and it's base and emitter.

The issue with mixers is that the available components only work with non-linearities that apply to both of the signals being multiplied.  Diodes, transistors and tubes all have this characteristic.  There are some good-working and well-known combinations of parts that cancel out the non-linearities, in both paths or just in the RF path.  This can make a mixer act linear as a block, but it's still depending on non-linearities inside.

(It's the same deal with amplifiers, by the way.)